# Left join not displaying products

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i have a query and for some reason left join is not working and i don't know why. i need left join because maybe some products don't have an image. But when i use left join no products are displayed, it works only with inner join. Here is my query:

```
$stmt=$dbh->prepare("SELECT 
 p.name,
 p.id_product,
 p.price,
 pig.image

FROM
 tbl_products p 
 INNER JOIN tbl_products_to_categories ptoc 
   ON ptoc.id_product = p.id_product 
 INNER JOIN tbl_catalog_categories c1 
   ON ptoc.id_category = c1.id_category 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_catalog_categories c2 
   ON c1.id_parent = c2.id_category 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_catalog_categories c3 
   ON c2.id_parent = c3.id_category 
 INNER JOIN tbl_products_images_gallery pig 
   ON pig.id_product = p.id_product 
WHERE (c1.name = :id OR c2.name = :id OR c3.name = :id  )
 AND p.active = 1 
 AND p.quantity = 1 
ORDER BY p.id_product 
LIMIT $start, $row_limit"); 
        $stmt->bindParam(":id",$id);
        $stmt->execute();
```

so i want `INNER JOIN tbl_products_images_gallery pig` replaced with `LEFT JOIN tbl_products_images_gallery pig`

Comment: Please dump your table in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Move the c2 and c3 conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result

Comment: that's not gna help me with the use of left join on tbl_products_images_gallery  instead inner join

Answer (score 0):

obviously an inner join will not produce the same query result as a left join- but I bet you know that already Chris.

Let me point to another -less apparent- reason that your left joint may not work as expected.
A.Check if your Database/table fields(columns) have specific constrains. For instance non-nullable fields. 
B.If such constrain exists on a field (used to join 2 tables)then doing a left joint that is expected to produce null records will simply not going to return null records. This is  because this is set in the constrain criteria of your DB/Schema.
C.If you run a simple  Desc 'Schema.Table' command should expose you the field constrains.

Hope this helps